# Twitter card not rendering - ERROR: Invalid card name (Card error)

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, twitter, twitter-card

I've added this card data to [this site](https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/):

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Long, Lead, Time, Capital, Intensive, Service, Parts, Profit, Optimization, aerospace, heavy, industries">
  <meta name="author" content="Ole Ersoy">  

  <meta name="description" content="Page description. No longer than 155 characters." />

  <!-- Twitter Card data -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Firefly Semantics Service Parts Help">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@fireflysmtics">
  <-- Twitter Summary card images must be at least 120x120px -->
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://fireflysemantics.github.io/logo/service-parts-help-center/fs-logo-help-center.png">
```

However when I paste a link into my twitter account the card does not render.

https://twitter.com/fireflysmtics

It does Render on medium.  Any ideas?

Here's an example medium article with the card rendering at the end:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/capital-intensive-concept-c565b5b5eade

It also renders fine on Facebook.

I found this resource:

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Put when I put the URL in it just says:

> ERROR: Invalid card name (Card error)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Twitter card can't have any random data in it. There are specified values that are allowed right now"

```
summary
summary_large_image
app
player
```

Comment: Abssolutly care about the twitter card (y)

eg:- <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>

Answer (score 3):

use `<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>`
If you want to add a custom description tag then put the following tag after the above twitter:card tag

```
<meta property="og:description" content="insert description here"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The card is a type, so it's literally supposed to be the value `summary`.

Answer (score 0):

The card shouldn't contain spaces, underscore( _ ) would work.